# Formula to count Text and dates by multiple criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have been trying to create a formula that will count the number of occurrences based on multiple criteria.  In the display below I am looking to populate cell **C5** with the number of rows that meet a given criteria. In this case, when the **start date** is between **C1** and **C2** and the **team** is **Green** or **Blue** or the **Department** is **WAZ**. I have been able to get counts to work based on just the date or just the team but have been unable to find a solution with all 3.

`Countifs` is what I have been trying but without success. I can only get a portion of the criteria to work.  As soon as I add in the date part it errors out.

```
Start   12/21/14     12/28/14     1/4/15
end     12/27/14     1/3/15       1/10/15
```

```
Project ID      start date     end date  team  Department   
1               1/7/15          6/26/15  Blue    SRT
2               12/27/14         1/23/18  Green   DFT
3               1/8/15           3/20/15  Red     DFT
4               1/3/15           6/20/15  Red     WAZ
5               12/29/14         7/12/15  Blue    DFT
```

[image]

Comment: where is your display?? add an image plz

Comment: The display did not post as i am a new user.  here is an idea of the page

Comment: can you give the expected result in your example? what do you expect to get that you are not getting? and provide us with what you already have tried.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/Y8E8TnG.jpg

Comment: =COUNTIFS(E10:E23,J10)+COUNTIFS(E10:E23,J11)    gives me count of projects in blue\green teams                                                =COUNTIFS(E10:E23,J10)+COUNTIFS(E10:E23,J11)*COUNTIFS(F10:F23,WAZ)       When i try to add in the or for department it does nto return corretly                                                                                       =SUMIFS(H10:H23,C10:C23,">="&C1,C10:C23,"<="&C2)    gives me count of starts between the dates

Comment: J10 and J11 are where I placed the criteria for the lookup.  I was trying to use a cell range but then just referenced the cell directly.  J10 was "Blue" and J11 was "Green"

Comment: see [Why Not Images of Code and Sample Data](http://tinyurl.com/kdxb7le)

Answer (score 0):

Supposing that you have the following criteria:

**J5 = red**

**J6 = DFT**

and your are looking for dates (start & end) in **C1** and **C2**.
I am using my example, please follow the data in the image below:
[image]

so put this formula in cell **C3**, which shows the number of rows for your query:

```
=COUNTIFS($C$5:$C$11,">="&C1,$D$5:$D$11,"<="&C2,E5:E11,J5,F5:F11,J6)
```

as you see the formula yields **2** because there are only two rows that match these conditions. (the rows are in bold, rows 6 and 7).

So basically a `countifs` can contain several criteria:
COUNTIFS(*criteria_range1, criteria1*, **criteria_range2, criteria2**, criteria_range3, criteria3 ...)

Comment: Very close AHC.  I have a similar formula for another count I have.  For this particular one if you move DFT to column I and add a 2nd team and\or department for the look up criteria.  What i am trying to get to is count if c1-c11 >=c1, and c1-c11 <=c2, and f5-f11 = I5-I7, or F5-f11 =J5. So it will count all items where start date is between the given dates, the Team is one of many from the list or the Department is one from the list.

Comment: @tcasteel what is the problem then? i can't understand it! i think this answer answers your question! doesn't it? if so, then accept it as the answer by clicking the check mark below the vote count of this answer. 
if not, then please clarify your problem with a good example.

Comment: I need to be able to have the date validated, multiple critera being validated in the team field and an or statement for the department.  The date needs to be between C1 and C2 which is there, then a verification of the department against multiple criteria such as red and blue, or if the department is set to DFT then count regardless of the Team field.   It should also return row 9.